# Setup routing on Ubuntu machine to ping between vlans

Tags: networking, network-interface, ping, lubuntu, gateway

I am using KSZ8895MQ micrel which is a L2 managed switch with VLAN configuration connected to micro controller. OS is Lubuntu with DHCP server configured.

I am able to get the different VLAN on the switch ports. When I connect different devices on ports they are able to ping all the gateways which are configured on Lubuntu. But all these devices cannot ping the other devices in different VLAN. I think I need to do some routing on Lubuntu to get it working. I have tried by changing `iptables` but with no success.

Comment: You could be more explicit about your setup. Is the Lubuntu host your gateway that is connected to every VLAN?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
echo "0" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/all/rp_filter
```

If that fixes it, set it permanently in /etc/sysctl.conf